# Way to create common name-based UUIDs in Java and PHP

Tags: java, php, uuid

Team Sof,

I have a requirement to generate name-based UUIDs for my project. The catch is that FE uses PHP to generate identifiers based on a string, and BE uses Java to create those UUIDs based on same string.

Is there some package in PHP and Java that generate same UUID based on a string. I tried to generate UUID in Java using `UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(name.getBytes()).toString()` method from `java.util.UUID`. In case of PHP, I am finding a module that generates same UUID

Answer (score 4):

Java's [UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#nameUUIDFromBytes%28byte%5B%5D%29) returns a [Variant 3 UUID](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt), Ben Ramsey's [Ramsey\Uuid](https://github.com/ramsey/uuid/blob/master/src/Uuid.php#L244) PHP library can generate these.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning my [Rhumsaa\Uuid](https://github.com/ramsey/uuid) library. Unfortunately, the link above is broken (I moved files around for PSR-4), but the library is still alive and well. It can generate version 3 and 5 UUIDs and is fully compatible with all RFC 4122 UUIDs. If you create a name-based version 3 or 5 UUID in any other programming language, this library is able to generate the same UUID, given the same "name space" and "name."

Comment: I changed the link for you @ramsey so the link works